# VIM - crazy command to replace/duplicate rows

Tags: vim, replace, duplicates, preg-replace

I have one gigantic file I need to update to create a list (list a csv) but I have only 1 column.

I want to create 2 columns with a key/value pair combo.

I have for example:

```
Key 1 is NICE
Key 2 is good
Key 3 is Awesome
```

I need:

```
key 1 is nice|Key 1 is NICE
key_2_is_good|key 2 is good
key_3_is_awesome|Key 3 is Awesome
```

So the first will be all lowercase with _ instead of space and the second one is the normal string

I have so far:

```
:%s/^\(.*\)$/\1|\1/
```

Which is good but how can I fix the space to be _ and all lowercase?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you can make use of having the second part of the substitution being evaluated as an expression as explained in the help below `:h sub-replace-special`.

If I have understood your question correctly, this should work:

`%s/.*/\=substitute(tolower(submatch(0)), ' ', '_', 'g')."|".submatch(0)`

`submatch(0)` returns the complete matched text in the `:s` command, the `tolower()` function converts it to lower case and finally the `substitute()` call replaces all whitespace by `_`

Answer (score 5):

Macros can be more intuitive than substitutions:

```
qq                                      " start recording in register q then…
0                                       " go to the first column then…
y$                                      " yank from here to end of line then…
A|                                      " append a pipe at the end of the line then…
<C-r>=substitute(@", " ", "_", "g")<CR> " insert text of first column with spaces replaced by underscores then…
<Esc>                                   " get out of insert mode then…
q                                       " stop recording
```

after that, select down to the last line and do

```
:'<,'>norm @q
```

Comment: sorry I am not a computer geek, I dont know what you talking about :(

Comment: I'm not a computer geek either but… you are using Vim, you are struggling with a substitution and I propose a slightly more intuitive alternative. With (almost) everything explained to you.

Comment: @PatREllery : No need to be a computer geek, don't worry. When you have more time, you should learn about VIM macros. If you already use VIM and know how to use :s , then it shouldn't really help you in the future to know about macros.

Comment: @max, macros and substitutions have slightly different use cases: it's good to know both. Even if you are comfortable with substitutions.

Comment: @romainl I just started using vim ... I have to use it now to debug code in production since my dev computer crashed

Comment: @romainl : it was a typo, I meant "should really help". What I meant was if Pat already knows substitution, he could easily pickup macros (as opposed to someone who's really new to Vim).

Answer (score 2):

As a start try this:

```
:%s/^\(.*\)$/\L&\E|&/
```

output:

```
key 1 is nice|Key 1 is NICE
key 2 is good|Key 2 is good
key 3 is awesome|Key 3 is Awesome
```

Read more at [vim.wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Changing_case_with_regular_expressions)